# Asana :how can I get Worksapce id from asana

Tags: java, javascript, json, asana

I am developing a small web application using java/javascript .
I want to query all the task associated with Asana for particular user .

I have gone through the API and i could find that as a request parameter need to have workspace Id and Api id .
Api Id i am able to found.
but no idea how workspace Id could be found.

could you please help me to get workspace id

Answer (score 1):

You need to call /workspaces to get list of work spaces. Choose a workspace from the workspace list.

Check this https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces